# Array modifier - cap location qurestion

Tags: modifiers

I used an array modifier cap function.
However, the model shown using the cap is out of the coordinates of the building modeling as shown in the picture. please teach me.[image]

Comment: The placement of the cap depends on the origin of the mesh.

Comment: Then what should I do?

Answer (score 5):

Start and End cap position depends on their origin points.
Simply move their origins to align them.

1. Go *Sidebar* (S) > *Tool > Affect Only Origins*
2. Select your Start/End cap object and move their origin using the move tool
3. Done

<sup>(Please excuse the crude demonstration, I'm on a touchpad :)</sup>
[image]